# How to change the glow of a jquerymobile slider

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I've just found out, how I can change the glow of the slider thumb:

```
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF0;
}
```

Now I dont know how i can select my id and switch the glow for every single slider. 
I thought it could work like this:

```
#slider1.ui-page-theme-a #slider1.ui-btn:focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF0;
}
```

But that's unfortunately not working. I hope you understand my question and you can help me :)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider1" step="5" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: added it to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply it to all sliders:

```
.ui-slider .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF0;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LgSSh/1/)**

**UPDATE FROM COMMENT:** OP wants individual sliders on the page to have different glow colors

jQM enhances the slider by adding a div next to the input.  Therefor any CSS or classes using the input id will not apply to the slider markup.  In your case, you have each slider within an `<LI>` in a list. So one workaround would be to apply the color class to the listitem and then create a rule for any sliders contained within the listitem:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li class="glowBlue">
        <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider1" step="5" />
    </li>
    <li class="glowYellow">
        <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider2" step="5" />
    </li>
    <li class="glowRed">
        <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider3" step="5" />
    </li>
    <li class="glowGreen">
        <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider4" step="5" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then the CSS would be

```
.glowBlue .ui-slider .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #0080f0;
}
.glowYellow .ui-slider .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF0;
}
.glowRed .ui-slider .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF0000;
}
.glowGreen .ui-slider .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #00FF00;
}
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LgSSh/3/)**

Another way could be to use jQuery to find the closest DIV with class .ui-slider and add the glowClass. In this case you could add the glow class name as a data-attribute on the input:

```
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li >
                <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider1" step="5" data-glowclass="glowBlue" />
            </li>
            <li >
                <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider2" step="5" data-glowclass="glowYellow"/>
            </li>
            <li >
                <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider3" step="5" data-glowclass="glowRed"/>
            </li>
            <li >
                <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider4" step="5" data-glowclass="glowGreen"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Update the classes:

```
.glowBlue .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #0080f0;
}
.glowYellow .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF0;
}
.glowRed .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF0000;
}
.glowGreen .ui-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #00FF00;
}
```

Run the following javascript:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $(".ui-slider-input").each(function(index){
        var className = $(this).data("glowclass");
        $(this).closest(".ui-slider").addClass(className);
    });
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LgSSh/5/)**

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was a bit missleading, I want to know how to set the first slider yellow the second one blue etc.

Comment: You are welcome, note that I added a second javascript solution which would work better if your sliders are not inside LI containers...